# Microphone input to raspberry pi 3 to work in browser

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi3, microphone

I attached a PlayStationEye USB mic/camera to my pi 3 and was able to get the microphone working with `arecord` with commands such as `arecord -D plughw:0,0 -f cd ./test.wav`. My `~/.asoundrc` is identical to the file shown here [here](https://wolfpaulus.com/embedded/raspberrypi2-sr/).

However, when I try to use the mic through the browser it will not work. I tried various websites with no luck. My end goal is to use this mic to do speech recognition via some platform but one step at a time. Any suggestions as to how and begin to start troubleshooting this? Chromium does show the correct default devices in the settings.

I'm at a total loss and there is little to nothing I can find out there. For examples [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42973654/raspberry-pi-usb-microphone-in-web-browser) does not apply because the browser certainly sees it. Could it be a latency problem of some sort?

Comment: did you found any solution to this?

Comment: No. I spent an embarrassing amount of time and no-go.

Answer (score 2):

If it works with "arecord" command, you should be able to capture the audio on the web browser as well.

You should check your Microphone setting under the Chromium Content Privacy Setting and make sure you select your USB Microphone in the drop-down options.

All the best.